# What is the name of the Math function (process) that programming languages such as Java use to progress through a set of integers by 10?

Tags: java, math

The code below that I have written in Java returns the reverse of a number. My question is what is the name for the math process whereby the formula for obtaining the value for my variable reverseNumber is

```
a =0; (a*10) + b = a;
```

I remember seeing this in one of my calc or statistic classes before, I just do not remember what it is called. Thanks.

```
public static int reverse(int number) {

    int reverseNumber = 0;
    while(number !=0){
        lastDigit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        reverseNumber = (reverseNumber * 10) + lastDigit;
    }
    return reverseNumber;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have a name. It's merely an algorithm. (I'm fully expecting somebody to come along and say that actually it's "X's algorithm". My point is: don't expect everything to have a name, it may not).

Comment: Key-phrases like "place value" and "powers of 10" apply here. No, I don't think there's a name for this though.

Comment: In Mathematics is a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472981/formula-for-reversing-digits-of-positive-integer-n) about that. No name is mentioned. Anyways, you can call the original and the reversed number permutations of the set of digits. What you remember is probably the modulo stuff.

Comment: Thanks to all who responded. I was just curious to see if it had a name. As I progress through learning java I like keeping notes and anything I can catalog like the Classes such as Math and Integer and then easily reference back to  really help me out tremendously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a function to reverse an integer, there is no direct function but you can achieve it using a combination of functions shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 135246;
        int y = Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(x)).reverse().toString());
        System.out.println("Reverse of " + x + " = " + y);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Reverse of 135246 = 642531
```

Check [Integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) and [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) classes to learn more about these functions.